# Django: Filter ManyToMany Relationship and must include Parent

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

If User Selects Product Sub Category as **Private Car** and State as **Andaman And Nicobar Islands**, I want to Display only those unique RTOs which matches in both Product Sub Category and State.

**View:**

```
product_sub_cat_data = ProductSubCategory.objects.filter(
            product_sub_category=selected_sub_product_array[2].strip(),
            product=product_data[0].id
            )
        state_data = State.objects.filter(state=selected_state)
        rto_grouping_data = RtoGrouping.objects.filter(
                            product_sub_category=product_sub_cat_data[0].id,
                            group__rto_state=state_data[0].id).distinct()
```

**Getting Output as:**

AN01, AN02, DD02, DD03, LD01, PY01, PY02, PY03, PY04, UP14, UP16, DN09, UP61, DD09, UP05, UP07, UP10, UP06, UP08, UP04, UP09, DN13, UP38, LD02, LD03, LD04, LD05, LD07, LD08, LD09, PY05

While the **Desired output** is:

AN01, AN02

(as only these 2 RTOs belong to Andaman And Nicobar Islands)

**My 4 Models:**

```
class ProductSubCategory(models.Model):
    product_sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class RtoGrouping(models.Model):
    insurer = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, 
              on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Rto, related_name='group')
    product_sub_category = models.ForeignKey(ProductSubCategory, 
                           on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Rto(models.Model):
    rto = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10)
    rto_state = models.ForeignKey(
        State, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='rto_city')

class State(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Comment: Assuming your output is from `rto_grouping_data`, can you use print() to output `product_sub_cat_data[0].id` and `state_data[0].id` and make sure your query is doing what you expect?